# An oracle in $\mathsf{NEXP}$ that separates ZPP from BPP

Tags: complexity-classes, oracles

Does there exist an oracle $A \in \mathsf{NEXP}$ such that $ \mathsf{ZPP}^A \neq  \mathsf{BPP}^A$?